# I couldn't vote to close a duplicate question with no upvoted answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

These two questions are nearly identical:

[Java logic in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379696/java-logic-in-my-code)

[nonstatic variable pRef cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377626/nonstatic-variable-pref-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

They were asked by different users, but the code is basically the same, and the asked question is only slightly different. Both users have a reputation of about 8.

Should we be able to close one as duplicate of the other, when the user is different?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels what are your thoughts?